# Linux - On boot do push-button-connect to strongest wireless

Tags: linux, networking, centos, wifi, boot

I'm trying to configure linux (in this case CentOS) to automatically connect to the nearest WiFi via "push-button-connect".  This micro computer has no keyboard or display, so the goal is to hit the "push-button-connect" then boot the device, so at init it'll search for the nearest router and auto connect.

My next option is doing a wifi-direct set up like chromecast to set the network credentials.

---

**1/5/15 -- Update**

After a bit of digging I've just about hit what I'm trying to do.  I've appended wpa_supplicant into /network/interfaces.  At pre-up it launches wpa_supplicant into the background.  After init, it then runs **wpa_cli wps_pbc any** which then runs through the available networks and attempts "push-button-connect".  Prior this is when you should trigger PBC on the router.

My new issue now is: after PBC, dhclient isn't able to generate an IP.  I can see the MAC in the network, but it doesn't generate correctly.  After restarting the device it is able to connect (since it's now stored via wpa_supplicant).

Next pieces to figure out are: If the connection exists it should skip PBC and connect immediately.

---

**1/16/15 -- Update**

I finally cracked it, turns out it is generating an IP correctly, it's just taking 30-60 seconds to do so.  Not sure if this is standard for PBC, experiments incoming -- Will answer with my guide thereafter.